# tensorflow audio recognition error 'Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found '

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, audio

I'm new to tf and I'm trying to read some audio for genre recognition. I'm following a guide from tf's website regarding this subject, but I keep running into 2 errors. The first is with this line:

```
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
```

It produces this error:

```
The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached.
In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of
the dataset will be discarded.
This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.
```

The other is with this line:

```
norm_layer = preprocessing.Normalization()
norm_layer.adapt(spectrogram_ds.map(lambda x, _: x))
```

It produces the error:

```
Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found
```

Here's what I have currently. I commented where Error 1 and Error 2 are and also where I believe the source of the problem lies:

```
import os
import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from IPython import display

seed = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

#Get audio
def decode_audio(audio_binary):
  audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
  return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)

#Get label
def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  return parts[-2]

#Get both
def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform, label

def get_spectrogram(waveform):
  # Here is where I suspect the source of my error to be
  zero_padding = tf.zeros([1600000] - tf.shape(waveform), dtype=tf.float32)

  waveform = tf.cast(waveform, tf.float32)
  equal_length = tf.concat([waveform, zero_padding], 0)
  spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(
      equal_length, frame_length=2047, frame_step=2048)

  spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)

  return spectrogram

def get_spectrogram_and_label_id(audio, label):
  spectrogram = get_spectrogram(audio)
  spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, -1)
  label_id = tf.argmax(label == genres)
  return spectrogram, label_id

def preprocess_dataset(files):
  files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
  output_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  output_ds = output_ds.map(
      get_spectrogram_and_label_id,  num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  return output_ds

#Work with data
def preprocess_dataset(files):
  files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
  output_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  output_ds = output_ds.map(
      get_spectrogram_and_label_id,  num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  return output_ds

#Get directory of songs. This directory holds folders of songs in mono channel .wav files separated by genre
#Each song is 30 seconds in length and has a playback rate of 16 bits
data_dir = pathlib.Path('path/to/Songs')

#Get list of genres
genres = np.array(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir)))
genres = genres[genres != '.DS_Store']

#Get list and randomized songs
filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/*/*')
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
print(len(filenames)) #prints 3936


#Separating songs
train_files = filenames[:2748]
val_files = filenames[2748: 2748 + 393]
test_files = filenames[-393:]

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

spectrogram_ds = waveform_ds.map(
    get_spectrogram_and_label_id, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for waveform, label in spectrogram_ds.take(1):
  print(waveform.shape) #prints (781, 1025, 1)

train_ds = spectrogram_ds
val_ds = preprocess_dataset(val_files)
test_ds = preprocess_dataset(test_files)

batch_size = 64
train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
val_ds = val_ds.batch(batch_size)

#Error 1
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

num_labels = len(genres)


for spectrogram, _ in train_ds.take(1):
    input_shape = spectrogram.shape
    print('Input shape:', input_shape)



#Error 2
norm_layer = preprocessing.Normalization()
norm_layer.adapt(spectrogram_ds.map(lambda x, _: x))
```

I really appreciate any input you have. Let me know if there is anything else that is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with header in the audio file itself. If you open it up in vs code you should see the header info. If the file extension was changed with a rename it *doesn't* change the header. Example below is a file that was recorded as m4a but the extension was changed to wav:

[image]

If I look at the headers on a file that was recorded as wav or properly converted it looks like this and it clears the header error out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that in the folder containing the dataset there were system files left by OS. (e.g. on Mac OS .DS_Store file).

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file first then calling decode_wav:

```
x = tf.io.read_file('path/to/your/wavfile.wav')
x = tf.audio.decode_wav(x)
```

Comment: This is a 2+ years old question; it would have been useful to demonstrate that previous answers do not suffice (if that is the case) and that your suggestion does.